# JavaMail attachment Decode Exception with Hotmail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, email-attachments, hotmail

I am trying to download attachments from Hotmail messages and getting the following exception: com.sun.mail.util.DecodingException: BASE64Decoder: Error in encoded stream: needed 4 valid base64 characters but only got 2 before EOF, the 2 most recent characters were: "JV". for every message with an attachment. I tried setting "mail.imaps.partialfetch" to "false" but it did not work,  here is the code i'm using:

```
public class imapHotmail {


private static Object m;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.security.Security
            .addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    Properties props = new Properties();
    //System.setProperty("mail.mime.decodetext.strict", "false");
    //System.setProperty("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");
    System.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");

    try {

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        // session.setDebug(true);
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        System.out.println("connecting....");
        store.connect("imap-mail.outlook.com", "soemone@hotmail.com", "pass");

        System.out.println("connected");

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();
        int x = 1;
        for (Message msg : msgs) {

            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(msg.getSubject());
            Object content = msg.getContent();
            if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                Multipart multipart = (Multipart) content;

                for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(i);

                    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                        System.out.println("saving");
                        //part.getContent(); this only returns the parts headers and 2 chars from the encoded bodypart
                        String name = part.getFileName();
                        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\" + name);
                        part.saveFile("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\" + name);
                        System.out.println("saved");
                    }
                }
            }
            x++;
        }

        inbox.close(true);
        store.close();
    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

here is the output i get if i call part.writeTo(System.out):

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pdf2.pdf"

JV
```

Comment: Did you try *props*.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");?

Comment: You're using the "imap" protocol, not the "imaps" protocol, so you would need to set "mail.imap.partialfetch" to "false".  To find out if the server is returning the wrong information, turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and post the debug output here.

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks it worked when i used mail.imap.partialfetch instead of mail.imaps.partialfetch whats funny is that this code worked before without adding that property